# Find text and replace it on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Scenario

I have a radio button question with the options of Male or Female

I then have second question saying "Has your pet been neutered / spayed?"

### Output

What I want is if the user selects "Male" the second question should change to

"Has your pet been neutered?"

Or if they choose "Female" it should change to

"Has your pet been spayed?"

### Development

I have tried replacing the text but this is not working.

```
var male = 100;
var female = 101;

$(document).on('change', '.petgenderradio', function () {
  if ($(this).val() == male) {
    $(".warrantyQ").first().find('.questionTitle').text(function () {
      $(this).replace(" / ", "");
      $(this).replace("spayed", "");
    });
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == female) {
    $(".warrantyQ").first().find('.questionTitle').text(function () {
      $(this).replace(" / ", "");
      $(this).replace("neutered", "");
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a Fiddle of it all together. Can anyone help me to get this working?

https://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/argz2fun/26/

Comment: I am unable to find `warrantyQ` in your fiddle, also It would be better to keep the values inside the script and put them in as needed, if the end user changes selection due to a misclick the other option won't be put back. [Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65bnhy8s/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can better form corresponding object with value and question. On clicking the radio button simply check the property and set the text accordingly:

```js
//create the male object
var male = {val: '100', question:'Has your pet been neutered?'};
//create the female object
var female = {val: '101', question:'Has your pet been spayed?'};

$(document).on('change', '.petgenderradio', function () {
  //check if value is 100
  if ($(this).val() == male.val) {
    //set the question from male object
    $('.warrantyQ .questionTitle').text(male.question);
  }
  ////check if value is 101
  else if ($(this).val() == female.val) {
    //set the question from female object
    $('.warrantyQ .questionTitle').text(female.question);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  questionWrap">
    <div class="col-msm-12  col-tsm-6">
        <div class="question">
            <label class="questionTitle">Is your pet male or female?</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-msm-12 col-tsm-6">
        <ul class="radioGroup  inputGroup__inline">
            <li class="radioOption">
                <input class="petgenderradio" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select your pet's gender" id="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender100" name="Enquiry.Pets[0].Gender" type="radio" value="100">
                <label for="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender100">Male</label>
            </li>
            <li class="radioOption">
                <input class="petgenderradio" id="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender101" name="Enquiry.Pets[0].Gender" type="radio" value="101">
                <label for="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender101">Female</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row questionWrap warrantyQ">
  <div class="col-msm-12  col-tsm-6">
    <div class="question">
      <label class="questionTitle"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can keep the text value on page load and replace from that value:

```js
var male = 100;
var female = 101;
var questionTitle = $('.warrantyQ .questionTitle').text();
$(document).on('change', '.petgenderradio', function () {
  if ($(this).val() == male) {
    $('.warrantyQ .questionTitle').text(function () {
      var questionTitleTemp = questionTitle.replace("spayed", "").replace(" / ", "");
      $(this).text(questionTitleTemp);
    });
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == female) {
     $('.warrantyQ .questionTitle').text(function () {
       var questionTitleTemp = questionTitle.replace("neutered", "").replace(" / ", "");
       $(this).text(questionTitleTemp);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  questionWrap">
    <div class="col-msm-12  col-tsm-6">
        <div class="question">
            <label class="questionTitle">Is your pet male or female?</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-msm-12 col-tsm-6">
        <ul class="radioGroup  inputGroup__inline">
            <li class="radioOption">
                <input class="petgenderradio" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select your pet's gender" id="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender100" name="Enquiry.Pets[0].Gender" type="radio" value="100">
                <label for="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender100">Male</label>
            </li>
            <li class="radioOption">
                <input class="petgenderradio" id="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender101" name="Enquiry.Pets[0].Gender" type="radio" value="101">
                <label for="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender101">Female</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row questionWrap warrantyQ">
  <div class="col-msm-12  col-tsm-6">
    <div class="question">
      <label class="questionTitle">Has your pet been neutered / spayed?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to just replace certain words. Instead of replacing the whole sentence as there is another function that changes "your pet" with the users Pet Name that they have entered?

Comment: @BarryCorrigan, please check the second answer that uses another span element inside `questionTitle`.

Comment: Thanks for that and looks great but unfortunately I am unable to alter the question text as it's being read from a database.

Comment: @BarryCorrigan, please check the second answer now:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var male = 100;
var female = 101;

$('input[type=radio][class=petgenderradio]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == male) {
        $(".warrantyQ").first().find('.questionTitle').text( "Has your pet been neutered" );
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == female) {
        $(".warrantyQ").first().find('.questionTitle').text( "Has your pet been spayed" );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  questionWrap">
    <div class="col-msm-12  col-tsm-6">
        <div class="question">
            <label class="questionTitle">Is your pet male or female?</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-msm-12 col-tsm-6">
        <ul class="radioGroup  inputGroup__inline">
                <li class="radioOption">
                    <input class="petgenderradio" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select your pet's gender" id="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender100" name="Enquiry.Pets[0].Gender" type="radio" value="100">
                    <label for="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender100">Male</label>
                </li>
                <li class="radioOption">
                    <input class="petgenderradio" id="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender101" name="Enquiry.Pets[0].Gender" type="radio" value="101">
                    <label for="Enquiry_Pets_0__Gender101">Female</label>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row questionWrap warrantyQ">
  <div class="col-msm-12  col-tsm-6">
    <div class="question">
      <label class="questionTitle">Has your pet been neutered / spayed?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider always leaving a comment or explanation in your answer so the OP knows what you have done and why this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping to keep it to replacing words only. As there is another function that replaces the term "your pet" with whatever the user types in for their pet name.

Comment: Replace isn't a good practice because once you replace the text, you can't find any text to update for the next radio button.

Comment: you should add something like this <span>neutered / spayed </span>

Comment: I am unable to change the structure of the question as its coming from a database hence why I am trying to use the .repalce() method